# Show array values for a specific letter

Tags: php, loops

The below code shows all values store in an array but my target output is showing only values that start with the letter T.

Can someone help me to convert this code to extract only values that start with the letter T?

```
<?php
$cars=array("Volvo1","Volvo2","Volvo3","Volvo4","Volvo5","Volvo6",
            "BMW1","BMW2","BMW3","BMW4","BMW5","BMW"6,
            "Toyota1","Toyota2","Toyota3","Toyota4","Toyota5","Toyota6");
$arrlength=count($cars);

for($x = 0;$x < $arrlength; $x++)
  {
  echo $cars[$x];
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this?

```
<?php
       $cars=array("Volvo1","Volvo2","Volvo3","Volvo4","Volvo5","Volvo6","BMW1","BMW2","BMW3","BMW4","BMW5","BMW", "Toyota1","Toyota2","Toyota3","Toyota4","Toyota5","Toyota6");
       $arrlength=count($cars);

       for($x = 0;$x < $arrlength; $x++)
       {
            // substr(string, start, length)
            if(substr($cars[$x], 0, 1) === 'T')
            {
               echo $cars[$x];
               echo "<br>";
            }

            // or use this
            // 0 is first character of the string
            if($cars[$x][0] === 'T')
            {
               echo $cars[$x];
               echo "<br>";
            }

        }
?>
```

But a better way is instead of using a `for` loop just use a `foreach` loop, as shown below,

```
<?php
           $cars=array("Volvo1","Volvo2","Volvo3","Volvo4","Volvo5","Volvo6","BMW1","BMW2","BMW3","BMW4","BMW5","BMW", "Toyota1","Toyota2","Toyota3","Toyota4","Toyota5","Toyota6");

           foreach($cars as $car)
           {
                // substr(string, start, length)
                if(substr($car, 0, 1) === 'T')
                {
                   echo $car;
                   echo "<br>";
                }

                // or use this
                // 0 is first character of the string
                if($car[0] === 'T')
                {
                   echo $car;
                   echo "<br>";
                }

            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$cars=array("Volvo1","Volvo2","Volvo3","Volvo4","Volvo5","Volvo6",
            "BMW1","BMW2","BMW3","BMW4","BMW5","BMW6",
            "Toyota1","Toyota2","Toyota3","Toyota4","Toyota5","Toyota6");
$arrlength=count($cars);

$key = "T"; //Or what you want
for($x = 0;$x < $arrlength; $x++)
  {
    if($cars[$x][0]==$key) 
    {
        echo $cars[$x];
        echo "<br>";
    }   
  }
?>
```